# Adding events and functions on elements generated with createElement()

Tags: javascript

I created different elements-paragraphs with createElement()/createTextNode() and added them to the body.

My problem is that i want to make those divs links or be able to add events such as onclick and obviously there is no HTML code to do that..just javascript generated objects.

my code atm:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
   var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   newDiv.className = "block";
    var heading = document.createElement("h2");
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(data[1][i]);
    heading.className="title";
    heading.appendChild(newContent);
    newDiv.appendChild(heading);
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    var newContent2 = document.createTextNode(data[2][i]);
    paragraph.className="light";
    paragraph.appendChild(newContent2);
    newDiv.appendChild(paragraph);

    var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
   document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);


  }
```

Comment: Once you add them to the `body` you can select them just like any other elements on the page.  You can add attributes to the elements, like an `id`, to make selecting them easier.

Comment: Not certain what issue is? You can attach event to created element following `.createElement()` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the event listener to the object you just created. The object does not have to be HTML. [Read more about adding event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and see simple example:

```js
var someDiv = document.createElement('div');
var txt = document.createTextNode('click me');
someDiv.append(txt);
document.body.append(someDiv);

var myFancyFunction = function() {
    alert('you clicked me');
};

someDiv.addEventListener('click', myFancyFunction);
```

**Update** after your code you can add an event listener to those objects you create on the fly. You can also add different functions on the same event. In this case it's the same function for both elements/objects .. play with this: (I changed the data to "dummy data" as there was no data)

```js
var myClick = function(event) {
    alert(event.target.innerHTML);
};

for (i=0; i<10; i++){
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.className = "block";
  var heading = document.createElement("h2");
  var newContent = document.createTextNode('dummy data1 index: ' + i);
  heading.className="title";
  heading.appendChild(newContent);
  newDiv.appendChild(heading);
  var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  var newContent2 = document.createTextNode('dummy data2 index: ' + i);
  paragraph.className="light";
  paragraph.appendChild(newContent2);
  newDiv.appendChild(paragraph);

  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);

  heading.addEventListener('click', myClick);
  paragraph.addEventListener('click', myClick);

}
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, why it works, ideally references to more information...

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder thanks for your comment! You're right! I'm working on it

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful. I create different elements with a for loop. I guess i need to assign ID to them with a variable to target them

Comment: @Kostis noooo, no ID! wait I'll check your code and update my answer.

Comment: Ah great, thanks a bunch. It took me while to understand it since I am quite new to Javascript but i get it now. I will test it on my editor

Answer (score 0):

Once an element is added to the `dom`, you can select it just like any other element.

```js
// Create the element
var paragraph = document.createElement('p');

// Give it an `id`
paragraph.id = 'foo';

// Add the element to the `dom`
document.body.appendChild(paragraph);

// Add the listener
paragraph.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.innerHTML = 'It was clicked';
});
```

```css
p {
  height:20px;
  padding:10px;
  outline:1px solid #bada55;
}
```

In the example above, I added an `id`.  If for some reason you need to re-select the element it may make it easier.

Comment: There's exactly **zero** reason to do `getElementById` above (and no reason for the `id`, for this purpose anyway). You *already* have a reference to the element in `paragraph`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True.  Added that to the answer.  I will say that adding an `id` isn't necessarily a bad idea though.  You might need to select it later with a plugin or something.  Who knows?  Thanks for pointing that out though, was going quick and without thought :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on the JS-generated objects, even before they are inserted into the DOM, or are never inserted at all:

```
let div = document.createElement('div');

div.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // do something
});

// This will trigger a call of the registered click callback,
// regardless of whether the div is in the DOM:
div.dispatchEvent(new Event('click', {
    "bubbles": true,
    "cancelable": false,
}));

// To add it to the DOM, simply add it the way you wish:
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

- [EventTarget.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) allows you to trigger an event in a computational way (has equivalent effect to actually clicking the `div`)
- Do take note of the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event#Browser_compatibility) of the event constructor in the example above.